# how to get active Wifi network operator name in android 9 using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need the wifi connected device name. The following code is working correct on Android 8.0. But it returns null on Android 9.0

```
var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
var activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo.ExtraInfo;
```

Can anyone give me the solutions.

Comment: Yeah, it is working. Thanks for your help Leo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Android 9, the permission requirements for an app to perform Wi-Fi scans are more strict than in previous versions. 
>   so first ,ensure that the required permissions have been requested [Wi-Fi](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#restricted_access_to_wi-fi_location_and_connection_information)

then ,you could try to get the **SSID** :

```
 var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.GetNetworkInfo(ConnectivityType.Wifi);
        if (networkInfo.IsConnected)
        {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.ConnectionInfo;
            string name = networkInfo.ExtraInfo;
            string ssid = "\"" + wifiInfo.SSID + "\"";
        }
```